# Why does this vim command fail?

Tags: command-line, substitute, global-command, sort

I'm trying to process large error logs and part of that is filtering out lines I don't need to see. Here's what I'm running in vim:

`:g/.*rsync: stat.*/d | %s/\(.*mkstemp "\)\(.* \/\)\(.*$\)/\2/ | g/[ERROR]/d | sort u`

Now, when I run these commands one-by-one, they work fine. The third global command - `[ERROR]`, seems to have some issue and running it in conjunction with the second or fourth command doesn't have the expected outcome. When I chain it with the second command I get `E147: Cannot do :global recursive`, and when I chain it with `sort u`, the sort command doesn't seem to run.

When I run the global command on its own, and *then* run the sort command, everything works out.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I have tried surrounding [ERROR] in double-quotes; no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For certain commands the `|` command separation operator doesn't work the way you expect. See `:h :bar` for the full list. Notice that `:global` is included.

So what's actually happening? The second `:g` and the other commands are running as sub-commands of the first `:g`. Or to put it another way, for a given line, nothing on that command line will be executed unless that line matches the pattern in the first `:g`. Note also, that that means your substitution and sort will be run *for every line that matches that same pattern*!

For complete separation/independence of the four commands you have on that command line you'll need to use a little "trick"...

```
:exe "g/.*rsync: stat.*/d" | %s/\(.*mkstemp "\)\(.* \/\)\(.*$\)/\2/ 
    \ | exe "g/\[ERROR]/d" | sort u
```

By using `:execute` to run the `:global` commands we can properly isolate them from the "bars" and thus each `|` will allow all four commands to operate independently.

(As DBK mentioned in a comment, it would probably be best to just split these up into separate lines if that's possible. You're trading compactness for readability, IMO.)

By the way, I'm guessing that you don't mean `[ERROR]` as a pattern since that's equivalent to `[ERO]`, i.e. you will match occurrences of any of those three letters, individually. Try: `\[ERROR]`

Comment: Though at this point I would drop the commands in a script, one per line(s), and source or runtime it.

Comment: Yeah, me, too. :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble why?

Comment: @Harv easier to type, edit, run…